# Excel on Mac - First worksheet overwritten with the second

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, spreadsheet

So I'm new to Mac and I'm working with a spreadsheet in Microsoft Excel. It has one worksheet in it initially. While I'm working with it, I start putting things into a second worksheet. When I'm done, I save and close the program. Then the next time I open the file, it only has the second worksheet, the first one has disappeared entirely. Oddly enough, the name of the sheet is the same as the missing one.

I've tried hitting the save button on each page individually. I've also hit 'save' when it asks me while I'm closing it. Which is also odd because it'll ask me that even though I just saved everything manually and made no additional changes.

Comment: work*sheet* or work*book*. A lot of what you're describing sounds like you are treating one as if it was the other.

Comment: This is all within the same file (workbook). The second page (worksheet) survives and adopts the page name as the first page (worksheet). The first page (worksheet) is gone.

Comment: Is it just the one workbook? Could be some kind of file corruption. It's not something I've ever seen happen before.